# Thumbnaill showing an example image if is not set - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I want to merge two function in wordpress thumbnail code; i want to shown an example image, if the thumbnail is not inserted in the post.

This is the section that set the thumbnail:

```
 $output .=  '<div class="post-image"><a href="'. get_permalink($post_id) .'">
                        '. get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'latest-post' )  .' 
                    </a></div>';        

                }
```

i want to shown an image if the thumbnail is not set, like this part:

```
} else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/img/media/media1-medium.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
```

So, how i can merge the two function?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
if( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
  // Runs if post has thumbnail
} else {
  // Runs if post has NOT thumbnail
}
```